# Writting in file and reading with the same format but error,java

Tags: java, file, io

I am writting to file user input and then reading it.
For writting in to file I am using such formatter

```
output.format("%-10s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s\n",
                                        year_n,
                                        months[month_n],                        
                                        record.getIncome(),
                                        df.format(record.getAtv()),
                                        df.format(record.getSumAtv()),
                                        df.format(iedz),
                                        df.format(soc_apd),
                                        df.format(netto));
```

To read the same file again I am using exact the same form, but it says that can't read that file.

Code for reader.

```
try {
            while(input.hasNext())
            {
                record.setYear(input.nextInt());//nolasa vērtības no faila
                record.setMonth(input.nextInt());
                record.setIncome(input.nextDouble());
                record.setAtv(input.nextDouble());
                record.setSumAtv(input.nextDouble());
                record.setIedz(input.nextDouble());
                record.setSoc_apd(input.nextDouble());
                record.setNetto(input.nextDouble());                

                ///rezultātu attēlošana
        System.out.printf("%-10s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%n", //parāda uz ekrāna
                record.getYear(), // piešķir objektam record
                record.getMonth(),
                record.getIncome(),
                record.getAtv());   
                record.getSumAtv();
                record.getIedz();
                record.getSoc_apd();
                record.getNetto();
            }
```

Before some of recent changes it worked just fine.
I though that is because I formated double variables just for 2 integers after comma ?
That could be the problem?

I have catch exception setted up like this :

```
catch (NoSuchElementException elementException){
            System.err.println("Fails nepareizi noformēts");
                input.close();
                System.exit(1); 
        }
```

Each time I try to read file I got this exception.

File that is written looks like this :

```
2013      Oktobris            50000.0             400                 445                 11893.2             5451.05             32655.75
```

Thanks, Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Please elaborate on "but it says that can't read that file"

Comment: When you write a single record: What does the file look like?

Comment: @reto Single line looks like this.

Comment: `record.setMonth(input.nextInt());` will not read 'Oktobris' - you either have to read a String there or store the months as integer values.

Comment: @reto I changed to String, but still the same problem. Should I go back to Int but just write all int or double types to file ?

Comment: Please make sure that all the datatypes are exactly the same when written and when read. I'd recommend you to go back to integers. If this works you can figure out how doubles have to be formatted / written so that they can be read again.

Comment: Why are you using a text file? I would use a binary file for this, with DataOutputStream and DataInputStream. Much quicker (no parsing) and much smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found sollution.
Problem was that there is no such:

```
record.setMonth(input.nextString());
```

When reading string from txt file, but just:

```
record.setMonth(input.next());
```

Thanks :)